# Chain HTTP calls

Tags: http, angular

I have a REST API that returns an array of appointments. For each item in this array I want to make an single call against another API to get more Information for the item.

```
   this.httpClient.get(this.serverUrl, this.httpOptions.RequestOptions)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map((items: Array<any>) => {
            let list: Array<MettAppointmentModel> = [];
              if (items) {
              items.forEach(item => {
                let model = new MettAppointmentModel();
                model.Created = item.created;
                model.CreatedBy = item.createdBy;
                model.Date = item.date;
                model.Id = item._id;
                model.participated = this.httpClient.get(this.serverUrl + model.Id, this.httpOptions).map(response => return response.json());
                list.push(model);
          });
        }
        return list;
   } );
```

I don't know how to get another call chained in this call

```
model.participated = this.httpClient.get(this.serverUrl + model.Id, this.httpOptions).map(response => return response.json());
```